# Matrix multiplication in C with unknown sizes

Tags: c

As a C newbie I am struggeling with matrix multiplication in C. The problem is, that the multiplication should be flexible and the rows, cols are not known before.

The dimensions, matrices and results for different matrix multiplications are all defined in an header file however I would like to have an matrix multiplication function that works for all of them.

Up to now I have:

```
void matrix_multiply(int rows1, int cols1,  int cols2, float matrix1[rows1][cols1], const float matrix2[cols1][cols2], float result[rows1][cols2])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols2; j++)
    {
      result[i][j] = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < cols1; k++)
      {
        result[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My local compiler accepts that. However when I try with other compilers at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) the compiler may return an error. It seems to compile with gcc and clang however with others I get errors:

x86 msvc v19.27:

```
<source>(2): error C2057: expected constant expression
<source>(2): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
<source>(2): error C2087: 'matrix1': missing subscript
<source>(2): error C2087: 'matrix2': missing subscript
<source>(2): error C2087: 'result': missing subscript
```

Is there a way to programm a matrix multiplication function that works for every compiler?

Comment: You're using [*variable-length arrays*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which have been in the C language since the C99 standard. Unfortunately Microsoft is a little slow and haven't fully added that to their compilers. Your code is fine, the MSVC compiler isn't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude does the compiler use malloc internally for such variable length arrays?

Comment: @Fra93 I don't know of any compiler that does. It allocates VLA's like any other local variable, usually on the stack.

Comment: What about compilers on microcontrollers like SDCC? Does not seem to work there.

Comment: MSVC is horrible example of a C compiler. Please, use a modern compiler like GCC/CLANG.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why your code works, it should fail on every C compiler.

There can be at most one variable dimension size.

You have two option:

Change 2d-array into array of arrays:

```
void matrix_multiply(
        int rows1, int cols1, int cols2,
        const float *matrix1[],
        const float *matrix2[],
              float *result[])
```

Or, just use 1-dimensional row-major array. For example:

```
// 2-dimensional array
int x[ROWS][COLS];

// can be replaced by
int y[ROWS*COLS];

// where element
x[r][c];

// corresponds to
y[r*COLS+c];
```

Comment: *"it should fail on every C compiler"* Back in the 90's. C99 introduced [variably-modified types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays), C11 made them optional. MSVC, beeing essentially a C++ compiler, never supported this feature, but the next C23 will mandate support for VM types and VLAs with allocated storage durations.

Comment: Would this approach work for C in the 90's?

Comment: `const float *matrix1[]` is an "array of pointers". It is neither compatible with 2D array nor 1D array.

Comment: @Erdbeer0815: Both approaches work with old compilers. Don't bother with two-level arrays and use a flat, row-major array as the poster suggested. Write a [little helper macro](https://ideone.com/ACj6Fi) to make the code more readable.